# rxdart replaySubject stream to listview in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, stream, observable, rxdart

When replaySubject stream is not in list type ,is there any way to display all the values from a replaySubject stream to a listview?

Comment: Can you please mention the detailed usecase here?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
myReplaySubject.values // List<T>
```

is a synchronous list containing the latest [values](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ReplaySubject/values.html) saved in the ReplaySubject.